# C#: asp.net CORE empty Migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to add a migration from `DatabaseContext` 
but when I add an migration i generates it empty like this. I had been following this tutorial

```
namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class ModelMigration : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

these are the models,Migration Configuration, Startup and `DatabaseContext`

`Movie.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {   
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int MovieId { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Customer.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsCreated { get; set; }
        public int MaxMovies { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime? LastEdited { get; set; }


    }
}
```

`Configuration.cs`

```
namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MovieExampleApp.Persistention.DatabaseContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(MovieExampleApp.Persistention.DatabaseContext context)
        {

        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
    }
}

}
```

`DatabaseContext.cs`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;


namespace MovieExampleApp.Persistention
{
    public class DatabaseContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext() : base("main")
        {
            //Database.Initialize(true);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using MovieExampleApp.Persistention;
using System.Linq;

namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
                        options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseContext")));

            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
            });

        }

        private static NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter GetJsonPatchInputFormatter()
        {
            var builder = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging()
                .AddMvc()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            return builder
                .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>()
                .Value
                .InputFormatters
                .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter>()
                .First();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can tell what im doing wrong.

Comment: If it's generating an empty migration then your database is probably already flagged as having the current migration. Check the migrations table in your database to confirm if the latest migration isn't the same as the one above.

Comment: I currently have no tables in Server Management Studio. So thats not the problem.

Comment: Having tables or not doesnt matter. If you previously had created an migration and then deleted your database, the previous migration (and snapshots are still there in your Migration File folder. EF Core matches your current model with your `DatabaseContextModelSnapshot.cs`. Only if there been some changes between your current and the previous snapshot that your migration is having any values

Comment: I deleted my migration folder updated database and enabled migrations. But when i added a migration it is still empty.

Comment: If you've done the above, then your database is already up to date. Once you make a change to your model, that will trigger a migration with changes. Try adding a property to your Customer entity and try another migration and you should see the added property in the Up and it's removal in the Down.

Comment: @Setherith I tried it but it still creates an empty migration.

Comment: Have you tried creating a migration with the verbose option to see if that gives any more clues as to whats going on: --verbose

Comment: I did it but i don't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the anwser to my problem.
I was using `using System.Data.Entity;`
instead of `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Here is the working code

`DatabaseContext.cs`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MovieExampleAppDotNetCore.Models;


namespace MovieExampleApp.Persistention
{
    public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> context) : base(context)
        {
            //Database.Initialize(true);
        }

        public DatabaseContext()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using System.Linq;
using MovieExampleApp.Persistention;

namespace MovieExampleAppDotNetCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


            services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, GetJsonPatchInputFormatter());
            });

        }

        private static NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter GetJsonPatchInputFormatter()
        {
            var builder = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddLogging()
                .AddMvc()
                .AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .Services.BuildServiceProvider();

            return builder
                .GetRequiredService<IOptions<MvcOptions>>()
                .Value
                .InputFormatters
                .OfType<NewtonsoftJsonPatchInputFormatter>()
                .First();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use as far as I know `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` as you use `[Key]` - this is enough to set Primary Key on property.

Try this way:

First I would remove empty migration by typing in Package-Manger-Console:

**Remove-Migration**

I also assumed that you do not have any other migrations where you have actually added these models you want to add now.

then:

`ApplicationDbContext Class:`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

I assume you got everything in your startup to update database but just to mention:

`Startup:`

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

     //some code...
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
    }
```

And of course update your connection string in appsettings.json to reflect connection name:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
"DevConnection": "Server=SERVER; Database=DB; Trusted_Connection=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;",

 }
```

Then type in Package-Manager-Console: `add-migration [Migration Name]`

Comment: I think I found where the problem is. 
when i try to add 

services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDatabaseContext>(
                        options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseContext")));
it doesn't see my dbcontext.

Comment: Your DB Context class is : DatabaseContext whereas in Startup you name it as: ApplicationDatabaseContext.

Comment: sorry I edited again they both are the same name but the error stays.

Comment: Okay so this morning I tried it and it worked but when i deleted the migration it started making empty migrations again and wich is really strange since i didn't change anything and now its still broken.

Comment: Is your migrations folder completely empty? But if you did migration and updated database it will not add another migration because models are already there! If you wish to clear your database you can do that either from SQL Server Management Studio or comment out your classes in ApplicationDbContext Class and add-migration. It should create migration where there will be "Drop Table Movies" etc.

Answer (score -1):

use this; add-migration migration1
before you call update-database

Comment: This won't help, it will create empty migration again. His solution is to call `update-database` or properly check DbContext and models.